# Programmatically change mouse cursor using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cursor, ng-style

What is the best practice for set the mouse cursor programmatically using Angular?

For example:

HTML:

```html
<div [style.cursor]="cursorStyle">Some content here</div>
```

or

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'cursor': cursorStyle }">Some content here</div>
```

TS:

```js
setCursorPointer() {
    this.cursorStyle = 'pointer';
}

setCursorDefault() {
    this.cursorStyle = 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are considering just these 2 options, the first one, since `ngStyle` and `ngClass` are better to use if you need to bind multiple properties, otherwise `[style.*] or [class.*]` would be better.